# Rtf datawindow,Powerbuilder

Tags: rtf, powerbuilder

Need to create  master template for word document. 
how to make header with image and right side with page no and report date.
RTF DATAWINDOW.
also at footer i want one more image to be foreground above the text

Comment: I do not understand, open MS Word you make the document and then load it into the rtf object of powerbuilder.

Comment: Why aren't you making the template in word and then loading it as part of the document creation process?

Comment: So you want someone to solve the broad & involved requirement for you? Hint: RichTextEdit control (not datawindow column) and template RTF file.